# Unable to disabled checkbox even after the checkbox status is changed in the database

Tags: php, mysql

My problem here is that i'm unable to disabled the checkbox after my checkbox status is changed to 0.
Here is my code:

```
<body> 
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE status = 1";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
$num_rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
$disable = '';
if (!$num_rows){
$disable = 'disabled="disabled"';
}

?>
<form method = "post" action = "">

<input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.1" value ="1.1" <?php echo $disable ?>/>
<label for="1.1" class="background1"></label> <br/>
<input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.2" value ="1.2"<?php echo $disable ?>/>
<label for="1.2" class="background2"></label> 
<br/>
<input type='checkbox' name="boxs[]" id="1.3" value ="1.3"<?php echo $disable ?>/>
<label for="1.3" class="background2"></label> 
<input type="submit" name="Next" id="Next" value="next" />
</form>
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
if(isset($_POST['Next']))
{   
foreach($_POST['boxs'] as $f => $value){
    $sql = "UPDATE box SET status = '1' WHERE boxid = '$value'";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$result = "INSERT INTO booked(username, boxid) VALUES('$username', '$value')";
    mysqli_query($con,$result) or die(mysqli_error($con));
   }

}
?>

</body>
```

My database checkbox status has changed but it put no effect on the checkbox.The checkboxs are still enable. Besides that, for the INSERT query, the username is unable to insert into the table, it just input an empty value. How can i solve these two problems?

Comment: (1) You are doing the `UPDATE` **after** you have displayed the html form, so you would have to do a page reload/refresh to see the change. Instead move the `UPDATE` code block to **before** your html form. (2) Your `username` is an empty value, as you are using `$_POST['username']`, but there is not a form element with the name `username`.

Comment: i was able to update the database, but after the status is changed, it does not disabled the checkbox. For this page, the user need to login before they can see it, so how to capture the usr username?